# Youtube-dl download speed

Tags: youtube-dl, download-speed

My script backs up certain video channels. Mostly the download speed is fine... but sometimes a video gets downloaded very slowly... and I have the option of either waiting for many hours until the video is finished... or I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and run my script again.

But... I don't want to stop my whole script as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> causes: "ERROR: Interrupted by user".

I want to interrupt that slow video only... so that youtube-dl retries to download that video "--retries" times before going to the next video in the list.

What key-combination should I use to interrupt the slow video-download only?

Second question:
"--limit-rate" limits the download speed...
Is there an option that measures the download speed... and when it's below a certain threshold for a set amount of seconds, the download gets interrupted and retried?

Torrent clients have the "re-announce" option to reestablish a faster connection... Does youtube-dl have such an option?

Tips are welcome.

Thanks,
Cheers,
user1366177

Comment: Please limit your questions to one question at a time: this is not a typical forum, but a Q&A site. The format of the site is: one defined problem, well defined solutions.

Comment: This is a known issue with `youtube-dl`. See https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/29326

Comment: Thank you Aenfa!
Any idea what key-combination I can use to interrupt the slow video (rather than my whole script)?